# CloudFront cacheing with "Vary: *" header

Tags: asp.net-mvc, caching, amazon-cloudfront

I've setup CloudFront distribution for a ASP.Net MVC site.

My homepage controller action is decorated with OutputCacheAttribute to control the cache-headers.

I'm having problems figuring out a suitable way to set the options for OutputCacheAttribute to allow CF to cache the homepage properly.

I'd like to be able to set Location:=OutputCacheLocation.Any in MVC, so the content can be cached at the server as well as at any proxies etc. However an odd side effect of this, is that it causes it to set "Vary: *" in the headers.

In CF, I've set all options for the homepage "/" behaviour, to optimise use of cache, including not forwarding headers, cookies, query string parameters etc.

From reading this...
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/RequestAndResponseBehaviorCustomOrigin.html

It sounds as though, "Vary: *" doesn't play nice with CloudFront. It will cause it to call the origin for every request, to check if the content has changed.

Does anyone know how to prevent my MVC controller from returning "Vary: *", while still allowing server side caching?

Comment: Curiously, `Vary: *` is semantically equivalent to `Cache-Control: private`, which explains why CloudFront does what it does.  It sounds like it will be sending conditional requests (e.g. `If-Modified-Since`) on subsequent requests.  Is there no `Cache-Control` header added to the home page?  Simple solution seems like it would be setting the minimum TTL of the cache behavior to whatever length of time you want CloudFront to forego checking with the origin again, and it should do that.

Comment: Thanks @Michael-sqlbot. I considered setting the behavior cache TTL manually, but that didn't seem like such a good idea, as I then wouldn't be able to customise it from my application code. What I ended up doing was disabling server side caching, by setting cache location to "Downstream". I decided it was a bit redundant using server caching as well as CloudFront. After doing this the cache headers worked as expected.